# Redirect to login page. Add a 403 error to response? How?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have the following action:

```
[Route("document/{id:int}"), HttpGet]
public virtual ActionResult Document(Int32 id) {

  Document document = _documentService.GetById(id);

  if (!ClaimsAuthorization.CheckAccess("View", "Document", new Claim(ApClaimTypes.AccessLevel, document.AccessLevel.ToString()))) {

    return RedirectToAction(MVC.User.SignIn());

  }

  return View(documento.ToModel());

} // Document
```

When I test this in IIS Search Engine Optimization I get the Info:

The page contains unnecessary redirects.

The link to "/document/4" has resulted in HTTP redirection to "/signin".

Search engines can only pass page rankings and other relevant data through a single redirection hop. Using unnecessary redirects can have a negative impact on page ranking.

Should I add an 403 (forbidden) before redirecting to SignIn action?

How can I do this?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Not really sure that it would be possible to return 403 and redirect. When you return a redirect, you are just returning a 301 status code with a URL. Not sure how you can return two status codes.

Comment: What's the purpose of authorization here then? Crawlers can only index  anonymous pages.